# Flutter windows app compile cmake error $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:testbed>

Tags: windows, flutter, compiler-errors

I'm actually trying to build a flutter app windows but i got this error message :

```
flutter build windows
CMake Error:                                                            
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:testbed>

  No target "testbed"

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
Building Windows application...
Unable to generate build files
```

The error was repeated about 20 times.
There is no problem with the `flutter doctor -v` command :

```
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.6.3)
   • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
   • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.6.30225.117
   • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.18362.0
```

If anyone have a solution, thanks to him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found where the error came from :
In the .\build\windows\CMakeCache.txt file at line 59 there is this :`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:testbed>`

To solve my error i just need to replace `testbed` by my project name.

Comment: there's no testbed in that file.

Comment: I deleted the `./build/windows` folder. It is recreated on a new building.

Comment: Deleting ./build/windows worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just go build folder in your flutter project and delete the windows folder and everything will be back to normal

Comment: This is not an answer if u want a windows build

Comment: @c-sharp-and-swiftui-devni yes it is, a new build folder with valid values will be recreated :)

Comment: This simple solution worked for me.